# boot clonzilla pxe doesn't try to up eth0

Tags: pxe-boot, clonezilla, lenovo

My server clonzilla work with lenovo M725s, but with the M720s it doesn't work.

When I boot in pxe the screen freeze and there's some error:

[image: sreen freeze when I boot pxe]

And it doesn't try to up `eth0`.

Comment: I encountered similar issue, when I try to run filezilla in another mode, if I remember goot there should be a safe mode boot

Comment: Thank for your comment ! I try to find this safe mode boot. But I don't think is possible with clonzilla server when I want to restore or save ... Now I think there are a config in live drbl for force to up eth0

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstanding you, I understood you deploy standard clonezilla via PXE

Comment: I want to save one computer with clonzilla . And after I want to clon in many other computer ! The probleme is the boot pxe with lenovo m720s

Comment: It's possible that clonezilla doesn't have the correct driver for that computer

Comment: I don't find any driver for network interface for conzilla. I'm stil searching !

Comment: I find !!!! i use kernel ubuntu